# Hex NSString to char[]

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a hex NSString and I want to be able to pack that to a char array.

For example, I have a NSString:

```
NSString* hex = "AABBCCDD";
```

and I want to be able to convert that to a char array for use with CCCrypt:

```
char bytes[] = { 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD };
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a for loop to go through each two byte hexadecimal character.  Then, use `NSScanner` to read it into a char variable for your character array.

```
NSString * hexString = @"AABBCCDD";
char * myBuffer = (char *)malloc((int)[hexString length] / 2 + 1);
bzero(myBuffer, [hexString length] / 2 + 1);
for (int i = 0; i < [hexString length] - 1; i += 2) {
    unsigned int anInt;
    NSString * hexCharStr = [hexString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 2)];
    NSScanner * scanner = [[[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:hexCharStr] autorelease];
    [scanner scanHexInt:&anInt];
    myBuffer[i / 2] = (char)anInt;
}
...
// use myBuffer here
...
printf("%s\n", myBuffer);
free(myBuffer);
```

Note that this will only work if `hexString` has an even length (i.e. divisible by two).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work....

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"AABBCCDD"];
uint32_t hex;
[scanner scanHexInt:&hex];
char bytes[] = {(hex >> 24)  & 0xFF, (hex >> 16) & 0xFF, (hex >> 8) & 0xFF, hex & 0xFF};
```

Untested as I did it in the browser.

Comment: Now that I actually look at what I wrote, you can just get the hex int and cast it right into the byte array and it'll do the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

I think you could use something like this:

```
const char* cString = [hex UTF8String];
```

Comment: This will give you the string value, not the hex value.

Comment: Thought that was what he was looking for. Must have misunderstood.