# How to converts these data into desire formate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, encryption, ios7

I have this type of data:

```
unsigned char 

datatoEncrypt[]="89f250de5d82d02e8b444984ecfec20b6456fdd6bcdc9b107b9a5eb339e6e5cf";
```

I want to convert it something like this:

```
   unsigned char finalHexData[]= {0x89,0xf2,0x50,0xde,0x5d,0x82,0xd0,0x2e,0x8b,0x44,0x49,0x84,0xec,0xfe,0xc2,0x0b,0x64,0x56,0xfd,0xd6,0xbc,0xdc,0x9b,0x10,0x7b,0x9a,0x5e,0xb3,0x39,0xe6,0xe5,0xcf}
```

Is there any library function in iOS to do this?

Comment: Well, I haven't delved into encryption/decryption, but at the top of my head, I think creating an array with `NSString` objects using `subStringFromRange` and `stringByAppendingString`/`stringWithFormat` will do what you are looking for.

Comment: None in the Apple pool, **as far as I know**.

Comment: can you put some code here

Comment: Looks similar to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969389/hex-nsstring-to-char